# Tomcat8 connection refused from other network

Tags: http, tomcat, tomcat8

Trying to connect to tomcat webapp in our customer network from my VPN-IP (10.41.x.x.x).

In front of the tomcat servers (172.23.206.x.x) there are a F5 bigip (172.23.202.x.x) VIP, which terminates the SSL and communicates to tomcat server on 8080.

I have fw opening to both 443 (to F5) and to each tomcat server on 8080.

Connection works fine on the customer network from clients. Browsing on IP and the DNS name. DNS is just internal, nothing is accessable from internet.

Also no issue when i run a citrix browser in the same network.

Accordning to netguys it's not a network issue. How can i configure tomcat to accept connection from this other network? Or is this clearly network related?

Comment: The VPN client / server need to be configured to let you go to the VIP address.  By default (well the 2 companies I know how the VPN was setup), having a VPN connection was not enough.  Network had to configure it to allow certain explicit address ranges.  If you cannot do `telnet VIP-ADDRESS 443` and get a successful connection, then it is clearly VPN config related.  IF Tomcat is refusing it, you would have a log entry (if put at maximum log level probably).

Comment: Hi, i'm able to successfully telnet to the VIP address. I will try to set a higher log level on tomcat.

Comment: Update: Turned on all logging. Should i try some other Ievel than FINE? cannot see any entries in the localhost_access log..